# Cómo poner una imagen de bakground en spring tool suite

Tags: css

Tengo el archivo css así:

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: none;
}

.full {
  background-image: url('../assets/img/fondo.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}`
```

pero no me carga la imagen, ¿qué puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

El fallo lo tienes en la propiedad `background-image`. La sintaxis no admite más que la url o las propiedades none, initial o inherit. La manera correcta sería la siguiente;

```
.full {
  background: url('../assets/img/fondo.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

o bien

```
.full {
  background-image: url('../assets/img/fondo.jpg');
  background-repeat: re-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```